# Data presentation difference in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, spyder

Hopefully a fairly simple answer to my issue.

When I run the following code:

```py
print (data_1.iloc[1])
```

I get a nice, vertical presentation of the data, with each column value header, and its value presented on separate rows. This is very useful when looking at 2 sets of data, and trying to find discrepancies.

However, when I write the code as:

```py
print (data_1.loc[data_1["Name"].isin(["John"])])
```

I get all the information arrayed across the screen, with the column header in 1 row, and the values in another row.

My question is:
Is there any way of using the second code, and getting the same vertical presentation of the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that `data_1.iloc[1]` returns a pandas `Series` whereas `data_1.loc[data_1["Name"].isin(["John"])]` returns a `DataFrame`. Pandas has different representations for these two data types (i.e. they print differently).

The reason `iloc[1]` gives you a `Series` is because you indexed it using a scalar. If you do `data_1.iloc[[1]]` you'll see you get a `DataFrame` instead. Conversely, I'm assuming that `data_1["Name"].isin(["John"])` is returning a collection. If you wanted to get a `Series` instead you might try something like

```
print(data_1.loc[data_1["Name"].isin(["John"])[0]])
```

but only if you're sure you're getting one element back.

Comment: Dan, thanks for that. How would I get the same to work for a number i.e.== 1234?

Comment: What do you mean?